# Find a text associated to a value in Excel

Tags: excel

Good morning guys,
I have this table below and I need to find the text associated to the biggest value in the table.

Can someone help pls?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `Excel365` then use below formula-

```
=FILTER(A:A,B:B=MAX(B:B))
```

For older version can try-

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAX(B:B),B:B,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a Pivot Table.

[image]

Note how the max value is 946 and the text associated is `Dummy Text 6`

Make a Pivot Table like this:

1. Field `Text` to Rows section
2. Field `Value` to Values section
3. Apply TOP 10 VALUES FILTER to field `Text`, choosing TOP 1

> [Excel Pîvot Table
> Filters](https://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-filters-top10.html)

That's all. The advantage of using Pivot Tables is that it may return several rows in case there is more than one record in TOP 1 position.

[image]